# The number of the shape of $2 \times n$ Young Tableaux is Catalan number

Tags: combinatorics

For $n\ge 1$, I'd like to prove that

The number $y_n$. that of $2 \times n$ Young Tableaux using letter ${1,2,3...,2n}$ is a Catalan number.

Catalan number $C_n$ is simply represented as :

$$C_n = {1\over{n+1}} \binom{2n}{n}$$

or, it's a triangulation of $(2n-2)$-gon.

The shape $2\times n$ Young Tableaux is the partition of integer $2n$ into two non-increasing size of sets.

How could I construct bijection between these two combinatorial concepts? It looks like there's some misunderstanding of definitions since to me, the Young Tableaux is way more smaller than the Catalan case.

Any guidance?

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1954309/whats-the-relation-between-standard-young-tableaux-and-catalan-number?rq=1) might help you.

Comment: The answer pointed to by Carl Schildkraut is the the better way to see this, but another possibility is to use the hook length formula for the number of standard tableaux; it comes out $n!/(n+1)! n! = C_n$.

Answer (score 2):

It is equivalent to this problem on counting votes. If two candidates A and B score votes a and b respectively. Suppose a is greater than b then the probability that during the counting process A is always ahead of b at all times during the counting process. This can be recast in to a problem involving lattice paths.

Comment: It would be great if you could expand on this a bit!

Answer (score 1):

The statement that the $2$ by $n$ Young tableau is a partition into too
non-increasing size of sets is rather confused. A $2$ by $n$ Young tableau
is an arrangement like this
$$\matrix{1&2&4&6&7\\3&5&8&9&10}$$
where the numbers $1,\ldots,2n$ each occur once, and rows and
columns are increasing. It is easy to biject these to one standard
Catalan family, the Dyck paths. These are paths with $n$ Up and $n$
Down steps, all lying above the starting point. Simply take the numbers
in the top row as locations of the U steps and the bottom row as locations
of D steps. This example gives Dyck path $UUDUDUUDDD$.