# Best way to calculate number of Young tableaus for a 2 × n grid

Tags: combinatorics

My question is:
Let $f(n)$ be the number of Young tableaus for a $2 × n$ grid. As shown below, $f(2) = 2$ and $f(3) = 5$. What is $f(5)$? What can you say about $f(n)$?

Initially, I thought that I'd go and write up the possible combinations for $f(4)$ and $f(5)$ to see what I can say for $f(n)$, but as I'm writing it up, I'm finding it very inefficient to do so. What would be a better way to find $f(4)$ and $f(5)$ other than grinding out all the possible cases?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2531867/the-number-of-the-shape-of-2-times-n-young-tableaux-is-catalan-number and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1954309/whats-the-relation-between-standard-young-tableaux-and-catalan-number

Answer (score 1):

HINT: These are the [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). Suppose that you have a $2\times n$ tableau filled with the integers $1,\ldots,2n$. From it you can construct a string $\pi=p_1p_2\ldots p_{2n}$ of $2n$ parentheses as follows: for $k=1,\ldots,2n$ let $p_k$ be a left parenthesis if $k$ is in the top row, and let $p_k$ be a right parenthesis if $k$ is in the bottom row. Show that the tableau is a Young tableau (i.e., that both rows and each column are increasing) if and only if the string $\pi$ is a valid balanced string of parentheses.

If you prefer to think of the Catalan numbers in terms of paths on the integer grid from $\langle 0,0\rangle$ to $\langle n,n\rangle$ composed of right-steps and up-steps and never rising above the diagonal $y=x$, think think of $p_k$ as a right-step if $k$ is in the top row and an up-step if $k$ is in the bottom row.

Comment: Did I miscount? I got 13 for f(4) and 18 for f(5) by brute force

Comment: @ninjagirl: Yes, you must have miscounted, because that’s way too many. And $f(3)$ is only $2$: you can have $1,2$ above $3$, or $1,3$ above $2$.

Comment: Shouldn't f(3) be 5? That's what the question also gives for f(3)

Comment: @ninjagirl: Ah, I see the problem: I was taking $n$ to be the number of filled cells rather than the number of columns. (This is more usual when looking at partitions.) Hang on a bit, and I’ll revise my answer accordingly.